# How to get full values in [Array]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

i have a POST request with some Data, i post with Postman , Data like this , But i have some problem is when i `console.log(newLesson)` i cannot get value in [Array] , but when i try `console.log(req.body.quizs)` its can !!! Can some one explain to me why ? And how can i get values from that ? Many thanks

```
    "name":"This is name",
    "videoId" : "this is videoId",
    "level" : "beginner",
    "script" : "this is Script",
    "quizs" : [
            {
                "question" : "This is question 1",
                "answer" : [
                        "Answer 1",
                        "Answer 2",
                        "Answer 3"
                    ],
                "correct_Answer" : "Answer 3"
            },
            {
                "question" : "This is question 2",
                "answer" : [
                        "Answer 1",
                        "Answer 2",
                        "Answer 3"
                    ],
                "correct_Answer" : "Answer 1"
            }
        ]
}
```

And this is my backend when received

```
module.exports.addNewLesson = function(req,res){ 
    let newLesson = {
        name   : req.body.name,
        videoId  : req.body.videoId ,
        level  : req.body.level,
        script  : req.body.script,
        quizs : req.body.quizs
    };
    console.log(newLesson);
}
```

And this is what i got

```
{
  name: 'This is name',
  videoId: 'this is videoId',
  level: 'beginner',
  script: 'this is Script',
  quizs: [
    {
      question: 'This is question 1',
      answer: [Array],
      correct_Answer: 'Answer 3'
    },
    {
      question: 'This is question 2',
      answer: [Array],
      correct_Answer: 'Answer 1'
    }
  ]
}
```

How to can i get `answer : [Array]` ??? Thanks

Comment: `newLesson.quizs.map(x => x.answer)`

Comment: You cannot see the nested array simply in the console log. In server side it aways shows in this format even for nested object it will not show. All you can do is stringify whole data and then check it. It will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try stringifying the output with formatting:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(newLesson, null, 4)); // 4 is the number of whitespaces used for formatting
```